# Setting Time on AlarmManager after Boot

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to add "reminders" functionality to my app and let the user choose between options like "remind me daily", "remind me weekly", etc.

so I just created an alarm:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BQBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 24HOURS,
                24HOURS, 
                pendingIntent);
```

so far so good. But what happens if the user restarts the phone? All alarm will be deleted on restart. I already have a BootBroadcastReveicer to restart the alarm, but what am I going to set the alarm-period to, after the restart?

let's say the user sets the alarm to "remind me in 1 day". Then the alarm is set for 24 hours. But the user restarts his phone after 23 hours. Then my BootBroadcastReceiver just sets another alarm in 24 hours. But I need it to be in 1 hour, instead!

How do I solve this problem? do I have to constantly check how much time is left on the alarm, and constantly write it to my sharedPreferences, so I'd be able to recreate the remaining time after reboot? Doesn't seem like a good way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calculate the time remaining until the notification is to fire within your `BootBroatcastReceiver`.

For example

```
private long getNextNotificationTime() {
    long value = // calculate milliseconds until next notification
    return value;
}
```

Now, use this value in your receiver.

```
long nextAlarmTime = this.getNextNotificationTime();

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BQBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                nextAlarmTime,
                24HOURS, 
                pendingIntent);
```

This means your alarm will ONLY need to recalculate on boot and then it'll fire every 24 hours.

Comment: how do I calculate the nextAlarmTime? how is the BootBroadcastReceiver supposed to know how much was left until the alarm?

 Does getNextNoticationTime() has to ask the AlarmManager how much it is left until the alarm? if yes, how often? every minute? isn't that too wasteful? every hour? if the user restarts the phone 59 minutes after the last check, then the alarm will be 59 minutes off.

is there an API that lets me wake up my app on shutdown, so I could recalculate it then?

Comment: AlarmManager won't know about your alarm on boot.You need to calculate that yourself in the BootReceiver and set your repeating alarm there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public long setAlarm( int id, int AlermHour, int AlermMinute,String title, String detail) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, OnetimeAlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("timer:" + id));
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("detail", detail);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, id, intent, 0);
        Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, AlermHour);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, AlermMinute);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long _alarm = 0;
        if(timeOff9.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis())
            _alarm = timeOff9.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
        else
            _alarm = timeOff9.getTimeInMillis();  

            alarmMgr0.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm,24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent0);

            return _alarm;



    }
```

Use this method and also use Alarm Hour, Alarm Min to set Alarm time. It will automatically set your time instead of calculation remain time.